# Is possible to use Stripe.com managed accounts with Parse.com Stripe module?

Tags: parse-platform, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I saw that Parse.com has module for Stripe payments, but I am not sure do they support Stripe.com managed accounts, since I am creating mobile apps for marketplaces and Stripe support told me that I should use managed accounts for marketplaces.

Parse.com Stripe module: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-modules-stripe

Stripe.com managed accounts: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts

Anyone with experience with Parse.com Stripe module?

Answer (score 3):

Parse unfortunately hasn't updated their Stripe API library in a long time and have stated they don't have plans to update it. Their API library is built against the `2012-07-09`version of the Stripe API which is a few years before Connect and Managed Accounts entered the Stripe API. Thus the Parse API library does not support managed accounts.

Comment: So, what solution then I could use? Own server for payments and Parse for all other?

Comment: You could use your own server (in this case I'd recommend just using your own server for anything). You could also just make web requests to Stripe's API from Parse

Comment: I have already a lot of backend wirtten in Parse.com, so I could make web request from Parse Cloud coide directly to Stripe API, and first of course call from mobile app Parse Cloud code? And after call from Parse Cloud code to Stripe APi then I should store data on Parse, or? Can you write more details, and then I will accept your answer.

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Cloud.html#.httpRequest is how you'd make an HTTP request, so instead of using the Stripe library, you'd end up just making HTTP requests instead

Comment: That sounds good. Can you please add answer with more details how would architecture system like this and then I will accept your answer. Also important option that I need is to hold funds from the user for a few days before I pay it to another user. Should I use Stripe Connect or just managed accounts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your account with Stripe has been set up to allow for connected accounts. By adding var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer; to you stripe cloud code outside the scope of the request, you can create an account using this code:

```
 var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
 var bankAccountNumber = request.params['bankAccountNumber']
 Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({

            method:"POST",

            url: "https://" +"api.stripe.com/v1" + "/accounts",

             headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer('YOUR_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY' + ':' + '').toString('base64')
              },
            body:{
                "managed": false,
                "country": "US",
                "email": "example@mailinator.com"

                },
            success: function(httpResponse) {
              response.success(httpResponse.text);
            },
            error: function(httpResponse) {
                response.error('Request failed with response code: ' + httpResponse.status);
            }
```

If you create a standalone account, you will receive an email upon creation. Mailinator is a service that allows you create working email addresses with any name, but there is no privacy.
Edit: I am working with connected accounts. I've noticed that when testing this, if you successfully create an account that subsequent attempts to create an account with the same email will fail. To transfer funds, Stripe requires certain properties that you can view under the connected account in the platform's dashboard. I've found the syntax for several of these (all except bank account).
Edit2: To complete the required fields for Stripe to verify your account you need to include a bank account field. My project is running in Swift and the parameter passed into my cloud code was a token created in my app using STPAPIClient.sharedClient().createTokenWithBankAccount and the test account information given at https://stripe.com/docs/testing#how-do-i-test-sending-transfers.

```
    body:{
                "managed": true,
                "country": "US",
                "email": "yourUniqueemail@mailinator.com",
                "legal_entity[first_name]": "AnyName",
                "legal_entity[last_name]": "AnyName",
                "legal_entity[dob[day]]": "20",
                "legal_entity[dob[month]]": "11",
                "legal_entity[dob[year]]": "1993",
                "legal_entity[type]": "individual",
                "tos_acceptance[date]": "1438198036",
                "tos_acceptance[ip]": "123.34.56.789",
                "bank_account": bankAccountNumber,
                },
```

Edit 3:
The way my code works is that customers are created and are charged. The charge amount is sent to the platform with an application fee. Then the connected account is payed out from the platform.(I am not completely sure this is the proper way to use Stripe; however, this method seems to work in test mode and allows us to store information about customers and the people we pay out.) Fortunately, the charge method exists in Parse's api, so we do not have to make a POST request. Here is the charge method that does this functionality.

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("chargeAccount", function(request, response) {
     var amount2 = request.params['amount']*100;

      Stripe.Charges.create({
        amount: amount2,
        currency: request.params["currency"],
        customer: request.params['customerId'], 
        description: request.params['description'],
        application_fee: amount2/5, 
        destination: request.params['destinationAccountId']
      },{
          success: function(charge) {
           response.success("There was a charge of $" + amount2/100  + " The application fee is: $" +amount2/500 +".");
        },
       error: function(error) {
         response.error("\nThis is the error:\n" +error); 
       }
      })
    });
```

Comment: Hi, can I contact you in private? if so, please send me your email, or anything where I can contact you in private.

Comment: You can contact me at jmjohns8@go.olemiss.edu

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/stripe-store-multiple-cards-on-a-customer) question on the parse questions section. I believe you should be able to change this code around to meet your needs. I haven't tested it, but by looking at [the stripe api](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#create_account), I came up with this:

here is the what the curl request looks like:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts \
-u sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2: \
-d managed=false \
-d country=US \
-d email="bob@example.com"
```

So your javascript would be something like this I believe:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({

//STRIPE_SECRET_KEY will be your stripe secret key obviously, this is different from the public key that you will use in your iOS/Android side.
// STRIPE_API_BASE_URL = 'api.stripe.com/v1'

method:"POST",
url: "https://" +  STRIPE_API_BASE_URL + "/accounts/",
headers: {
"keys[secret]" : STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
}, 
body:{ 
    "managed="+true,
    "country="+"US",
    "email="+"bob@example.com"
},
success: function(httpResponse) {
    response.success(httpResponse.text);
},
error: function(httpResponse) {
    response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
    }
});
```

This may not be 100% because I haven't been able to test it, but look at the following questions for some more resources:

https://parse.com/questions/cloud-httprequest-unable-to-take-dictionary-object-as-parameter-cant-form-encode-an-object-error

https://www.parse.com/questions/stripe-store-multiple-cards-on-a-customer